# Wordpress - Enable subscribers (frontend-custom form) change their email address

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

We have developed a custom dashboard (not woocommerce my-account) into our child theme. We want to give the subscribers option to change their email address from the custom dashboard via a form. For instance, they will enter the new email and a confirmation link is sent to the email address before it is saved as primary/ default user email for their account. So, I am just looking for a way to create the form on our custom dashboard and code it to send the confirmation link on the new email the same way woocommerce does from 'my-account'.

So, in short we would like to replicate the "Account details" (Edit Account of woocommerce) section in your own custom dashboard where customers are allowed to change email address. Woocommerce/ Wordpress send a confirmation link on the new email before it becomes active.

Thanks in advance.